# I am not able to add hover effect on border of the thumbnail class in html

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I extended the thumbnail class of bootstrap to add hover effects on the border of the thumbnail. But when I hover over the thumbnail, some different effect is displayed. The effect I added is displayed for a split second as I remove my mouse pointer from the thumbnail area.

`1` https://jsfiddle.net/bh8757v3/. The code is available here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using the `border` css property, you need to specify a `border-width`, `border-style`, and `border-color`. You are only specifying 2 of the 3. See [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/border) on the border property.

Example:
`border: 3px solid blue`

This works in the [updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bh8757v3/1/)